# Why can't I move all images to SD card?

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

I wanna move ALL my photos, videos, music, etc. to the SD card, so I can give my phone to a friend.

This is the space used by all that stuff and what I see when I click "Transfer data to SD card":

[image: screenshot 1] [image: screenshot 2]

Only 1 file! (The previous screenshot.) So, why can't it see the half Gigabyte of "Pictures, videos" from the first image, as well as the Downloads, Misc...?

EDIT

I'm using Android 4.4.2 on a Sony Xperia D2104.

Answer (score 2):

This would have to do with the manufacturer's implementation of the "file manager" you are using and where it is allowed to move files from and to, most likely out of your control but you did not mention what device or android version or any other information of use to assist in that capacity.

I would suggest connecting the phone to a computer and transferring the files that way, or using a different file manager such as one of the applications in [this article](https://www.androidpit.com/best-android-file-manager) which allows relatively full control over the file system and SD card.

Comment: Thanks. It is allowed to move files to the SD card, because it does so with the few files informed in the "Transfer files to SD card" screen (like the 1 file above). I have the ES  File Explorer, but it can't write to SD card, what is very strange, since lots of games and other simple software can do it. I'm trying to connect the device to my Ubuntu 14.04, but Ubuntu is not recognizing it (it used to, but now it's just not working). I'll take a look in the link you provided, and hope any of them can be installed in the 208 MB available. Thanks again!

Comment: Depending on your Android version, you need to approve the permission to write to the SD card the first time ES File Explorer attempt to do so... Create a new text file in ES in the root of SD and it should prompt you for permission. Personally, I detest ES... It used to be the king until they loaded it with extra garbage Junkware

Comment: Tried to Install Astro File Manager, but... "Insufficient storage". With 7.13MB of Download Size, it's UNBELIEVABLE that it cannot fit in 208MB of free internal space. Android SUCKS!!!

Comment: As the Android version is Kitkat, and if the device is not rooted, it is very likely that file managers don't get write access to the SD card. That's an issue introduced with Kitkat which was never really solved (except by some manufacturers applying a fix themselves, or some root-apps to fix it). With Android 5.0 and up applies what @acejavelin just wrote (approve the permission).

Comment: My Android is 4.4.2, not 5.0. I wonder how can a game write to SD card, but not a file manager!!! Also: trying to install OI File Manager (Download size: 603KB), but "Insufficient storage" again! With 208MB free space! When exactly did Google moved from "don't be evil" to "we're evil and proud about it"?

Comment: @Rodrigo Applications can write to their own folder

Comment: @acejavelin what is the purpose of an simple sd card, anyway? If we return to floppy drives, who knows it gets easier to use them to save some files?

Comment: But we're missing the point: why Android don't move the data to SD card? Why most of my personal data can't leave and free up the device's internal memory?

Comment: @Rodrigo Because KitKat's SD card access was "broken", read Izzy's previous comment. At that time it was assumed Google was trying to get rid of SD cards, only recently did they realize this wasn't going to happen.

Comment: Probably that's nothing but the bad old planned obsolescence.